# JQuery .scrollTop() function always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried change the css position and scroll-y property but nothing seems to work.
The function work for this:
`$('.class').scrollTop(100);`
That would move the div to the right position, but once there if I run:
`$('.class').scrollTop();`
It will return 0 always independently of the div's position.

Do you have any idea of what could be causing this problem? I am currently testing in iPhone's safari.

Thanks you very much!

Comment: can you share your code that you did? please

Comment: some where in parent tag have you using height=100%?

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I have not shared the code because the codebase its quite big.
The element which scrolls is a section inside another section. None of the parent tags have 100% height. Also for me the weird think is that after running:

`$('.sectionsClass').scrollTop(100);`   // Which works fine
`$('.sectionsClass').scrollTop(0);`       // Returns 0 instead of a 100

Comment: In order for anyone to help you, we need to see code. If your codebase is too big, you should create a small example that contains the elements you are concerned with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.